# SQL (Oracle) - Query to find all duplicates and leave only the most recently created

Tags: sql, oracle

So I am requiring a query that will take any search parameter (as seen in regexp_like) and with the query results find all the duplicates and only keep the ones with the most recent create date baring in mind that there could be different duplicates in a result set.

The example below is a table with 2 columns of 'name' and 'create_date'.

I so far have:

```
SELECT name, create_date

FROM (

    SELECT cs.name, cs.create_date,

    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cs.name ORDER BY cs.create_date DESC) AS     RowNo

    FROM names_and_dates_table cs

    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(cs.name, 'Mr Gary', 'i')

 )

WHERE RowNo = 1;
```

To clarify this would be used in a type ahead scenario for a web app so as the user is typing in the input field it is providing them with suggestions. In this case they have typed 'Mr Gary' with the intention of typing a second name.

Ideally I'd need the query (for this example) to look through all the records that match the regexp_like argument which could be a lot (or a few) and wherever there are pairs, triplets or more of the same name to only keep that name with the most recent create_date (obviously any other names without duplicates would also be kept).

I realise max(create_date) would get the most recent date but I can't seem to get this to work in the query properly.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close. I think that all you need to do is leave *out* the `partition by`, like this:

```
SELECT name, create_date
FROM (
    SELECT cs.name, cs.create_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cs.create_date DESC) AS RowNo
    FROM names_and_dates_table cs
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(cs.name, 'Mr Gary', 'i')
)
WHERE RowNo = 1;
```

Your regex already filters down to your matches, so just get the most recent one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select cs.name, cs.create_date
  from names_and_dates_table cs
 where cs.create_date = ( select max(nt.create_date)
                            from names_and_dates_table nt
                           where nt.name = cs.name )
   and REGEXP_LIKE(cs.name, 'Mr Gary', 'i')
   and rownum = 1
```

Comment: @Jorge_Campos - if the OP is already using windowing functions like `ROW_NUMBER()`, then a more inefficient (and risky) method using subqueries or self-joins is not what they need. For example, if there are two rows that both have the same create_date that happens to be the max, your query will return two rows instead of one.

Comment: @SlimsGhost the `max` function on oracle will always return just one row no matters if there are same dates. It will use an internal algorithm to find out which one is the max. See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9edb/1

Comment: @Jorge_Campos - yes, that is exactly what MAX() does, but if two records **BOTH** have the same create_date, then `where cs.create_date  (select max()...)` will test TRUE for both of those records (max() returns 1 value, but two records have that value as their create_date.

Comment: @SlimsGhost have you see the fiddle example that I provided? It proves that your statemant is false.

Comment: @Jorge_Campos - yes, I see, but the results being 1 row is because of the `rownum=1`, and *not* because of how max() works. Your suggestion does work, but windowing (or "analytical" functions) give the correct answer with *much less work* for the database compared to a correlated subquery.